# Expand occurrences into single events

Tags: outlook-restapi

Are there any options to expand recurring events into single events and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the underlying recurring events themselves?

Currently the Outlook Calendar REST API returns occurrences with their SeriesMaster, but we need to merge and expand them programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what `GET /me/calendarview` does. That expands recurring meetings and returns any instances that fall within the start/end parameters of the view. If you just do `GET /me/events` then you only get the series master.

If you want to expand from a series master you can always do `GET /me/events/{id-of-series-master}/instances?startDateTime=XXXX&endDateTime=XXXX`.

Note with both cases you have to specify a time window, so there is no way to say "just give me ALL the instances". This is because there is the possibility to have recurring events with no end date, so there is no "all" :).

Comment: Got it, thank you. Just one more question: Is there no way to expand properties like body or location for occurrence events on `GET /me/calendarview`?

Comment: They will be present only if they differ from the master. I don't know of a way to force them on there (assuming `$select` doesn't do it). The design is if it doesn't show, you should use the value from master.